# Context switching between python coroutines

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have a Python application in which multiple "tasks" will call `exec` function to evaluate multiple Python statements using a global "context" dictionary. The application would benefit tremendously by utilizing coroutines, but I could not find a way to create coroutine-specific context (global variables).

A simple example looks like this:

```py
import asyncio

context = {}

async def async_exec(statements):
    global context
    for stmt in statements:
        exec(stmt, context, context)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


def sync_main():
    asyncio.run(async_exec(['a=1', 'print(f"{a}==1")']))
    asyncio.run(async_exec(['a=2', 'print(f"{a}==2")']))

async def async_main():
    return await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.create_task(async_exec(['a=1', 'print(f"{a}==1")'])),
        asyncio.create_task(async_exec(['a=2', 'print(f"{a}==2")'])),
    )


sync_main()
asyncio.run(async_main())
```

When I execute the code, I get

```
1==1
2==2
2==1 <- problem here
2==2
```

because the actual async execution sequence is

```
a=1
a=2
print(f"{a}==1")
print(f"{a}==2")
```

Is there any easy way to save and restore context variables for coroutines?

### Working Code using Andrej's suggestion

Many thanks for the suggested use of `contextvars`, I am not sure how costly it would be to maintain fairly large dictionaries as `contextvars` but the following works for my application:

```
import asyncio
import contextvars

context = contextvars.ContextVar("global")

async def async_exec(statements):
    global context
    for stmt in statements:
        # retrieving the global dictionary
        gv = context.get({})
        # use the dictionary to evaluate statement
        exec(stmt, gv, gv)
        # set global dictionary back to the context
        context.set(gv)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


def sync_main():
    asyncio.run(async_exec(['a=1', 'print(f"{a}==1")']))
    asyncio.run(async_exec(['a=2', 'print(f"{a}==2")']))

async def async_main():
    return await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.create_task(async_exec(['a=1', 'print(f"{a}==1")'])),
        asyncio.create_task(async_exec(['a=2', 'print(f"{a}==2")'])),
    )

sync_main()
asyncio.run(async_main())
```

with output

```
1==1
2==2
1==1
2==2
```

Comment: "The application would benefit tremendously by utilizing coroutines...", is not always the case, if your statements don't make I/O operations, there is not going to be any improve of performance. Probably multiprocessing is the option in that cases with python.

Comment: In my particular case, there are multiple "tasks" that submit jobs to remote workers,  wait for results (through `zmq`) before continuing. I am using multiprocessing but there can be a large number of idling processes if tasks cannot complete in time (e.g. tasks that depend on the completion of other tasks). Using coroutines could turn idling processes to `await` coroutines.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you can use [`contextvars`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/contextvars.html#module-contextvars) built-in module:

```py
import asyncio
import contextvars

context = contextvars.ContextVar("Some context")


async def async_exec(statements):
    global context
    for stmt in statements:
        exec(stmt, {"context": context}, {"context": context})
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


def sync_main():
    asyncio.run(async_exec(["context.set(1)", 'print(f"{context.get()}==1")']))
    asyncio.run(async_exec(["context.set(2)", 'print(f"{context.get()}==2")']))


async def async_main():
    return await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.create_task(
            async_exec(["context.set(1)", 'print(f"{context.get()}==1")'])
        ),
        asyncio.create_task(
            async_exec(["context.set(2)", 'print(f"{context.get()}==2")'])
        ),
    )


sync_main()
asyncio.run(async_main())
```

Prints correctly:

```
1==1
2==2
1==1
2==2
```

Comment: This is great. The only problem is that the "statements" are provided by users so I have to manually translate their `a=1` to `context.set`. I may have to use `ast` to do this but this is a great start.